# nginx try_files on dynamic 404

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to mash together two PHP frameworks into a single installation. One is our old site, which has a ton of code... and one is new, which is an entirely separate codebase. Both process requests dynamically.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
try_files framework1.php?$uri framework2.php?$uri
```

So the first framework processes the request and if it returns a 404 error, it should attempt framework2.php

Is that possible? Is there any way for Nginx to intercept a 404 request (or any, for that matter) and attempt the next location?

If not - any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious solution is to catch all 404 errors and handle them to second framework:

```
error_page  404 =200 /framework2.php;
```

But it's causes problem with real 404 pages, so you have to return real 404 with framework itself if there is real 404 error.

Comment: If framework2.php returns 404, what happens to the nginx chain? Is there any way of adding a 'real' 404 in the event that both frameworks return it?